# Can not play video from my internal application directory

Tags: android

It looks like I can not play videos stored in my internal application directory.

I have videos stored in `/data/data/my.package.org/files/`

And I'm trying to play a file from there using

```
String fpath = "/data/data/my.package.org/files/video.mpg"
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(fpath), "video/*");
```

But both Android default video player and some external videoplayer (MX player) say 'this video can not be played".

Whereas when I'm saving videos to SD card they are played fine.

Why is that?

Comment: is your video file set to MODE_WORLD_READABLE?

Comment: @FoamyGuy How do I do that?

Comment: post the code where you are writing your video file to `files/` dir

Comment: Don't use hardcoded paths, use for example getFilesDir() and similar functions.

Comment: @FoamyGuy I'm creating a File f = new File("/data/data/mypackage/video.mpg"); and then I'm using Mediarecorder.setOutputFile(f)

Comment: You should definitely take RvdK's advice use the helper methods instead of hardcoding path. Also see here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteInternalStorage where they use Context.MODE_PRIVATE you want to use Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE.

Comment: @FoamyGuy I do use getFilesDir(). The problem is they are getting FileStream with MODE flag but the player it needs an URI

Comment: The mode is set when you create the file only, not when you pass it to the video player. Try using the stream to create a blank file with world readable. Then once it is created get a File object reference to it and pass that to mediarecorder.

Comment: are you deadset on using the built in Video application via intent? If you use your own activity with a VideoVeiw then you won't have to worry about making your file world readable...

Comment: I think I'm deadset yes... So now I'm creating FileOutputStream os = ctx.openFileOutput then I immediately close it. But how to get the corresponding (0 bytes) file?

Answer (score 0):

Put your video in assets folder and use this code to play video with MediaPlayer

```
InputStream is = getResources().getAssets().open("video.mpg");
```

OR

Put your video in assets folder and...

```
String fpath = "/data/data/my.package.org/assets/video.mpg"
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(fpath), "video/*");
```

Comment: I can't put my video in assets I'm creating it in my application

Answer (score 0):

put your video in the res\raw folder. Then copy it out to the external directories where apps like video player can read them.  Only your app can read /data/data/blah....

if its in res\raw, then

```
         typeName = sourceSink.Types.video.toString();
         for (sourceSink.VideoFiles video: sourceSink.VideoFiles.values() ){
             resourceName = video.toString(); 
             fileName = resourceName + ".mp4";
             resource = getResources().getIdentifier(resourceName, "raw", "com.invodo.allshareplay");
             createExternalStoragePublicFile(typeName,fileName,resource);
         }
```

and then you can use this to copy it:

```
        void createExternalStoragePublicFile(String fType, String fname, int res ) {
        // Create a path where we will place our picture in the user's
        // public pictures directory.  Note that you should be careful about
        // what you place here, since the user often manages these files.  For
        // pictures and other media owned by the application, consider
        // Context.getExternalMediaDir().
        File path = null;
        if (((fType.equals(sourceSink.Types.photo.toString())) || (fType.equals(sourceSink.Types.file.toString())) ) ){
            path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            }
        if (fType.equals(sourceSink.Types.music.toString())) {
            path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);
            }
        if (fType.equals(sourceSink.Types.video.toString())) {
            path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES);
        }
        File file = new File(path, "/" + fname);



        try {
            // Make sure the Pictures directory exists.
            path.mkdirs();

            // Very simple code to copy a picture from the application's
            // resource into the external file.  Note that this code does
            // no error checking, and assumes the picture is small (does not
            // try to copy it in chunks).  Note that if external storage is
            // not currently mounted this will silently fail.
            InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(res);
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
            byte[] data = new byte[is.available()];
            is.read(data);
            os.write(data);
            is.close();
            os.close();

            scanMedia(file);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Unable to create file, likely because external storage is
            // not currently mounted.
            Log.w("ExternalStorage", "Error writing " + file, e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

then it's easy - just do the second half of the answer I provided and write them out.  /data/data/ folder is never going to be viewed by anything other than your app.